# Maven create artifact from zip file

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

Please don't ask, why I need to this.

But I have a Maven project, where I have a zip file. I want this zip file to be the artifact Maven produces and deploys to our artifactory.

I know to create a zip file I can use Maven Assembly Plugin. But it's not that I have files I want to be a zip, I want the existing file which exists, to be the zip later used.

Comment: For (repository) "deployment" [deploy:deploy-file](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html#the-deploy-deploy-file-mojo)...

Comment: For (local) "installation" ...: [install:install-file](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html#the-install-install-file-goal) ;)

Comment: "The xxx:xxx-file goal is used primarily for xxxing artifacts to the XXX which were *not built by Maven*."

Comment: If you create a zip file via maven-assembly-plugin it will be deployed during the usual `mvn deploy` to you repository manager... Otherwise I don't understand your question?